# How to change folder icon in pantheon-files?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, files

How to change any folder icon in pantheon-files?

Does anybody know where is the config of user default folders kept in elementary? Maybe there will I find some file to edit.

I know I can't do it in properties.

I don't want to change the theme.

I don't want to use nautilus as default filemanager.

Comment: You can change the locations of user special folders by editing ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs.

Comment: THX for the usefull info. Still looking for a way to change the icons of those folders thoug...Or at least change the icons of newly created folders in Home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no facility to customise the icon used on a per folder basis using the Properties dialog like there is in Nautilus.  You might like to file a ""wishlist" issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues but there is no guarantee it will be implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I have changed by editing the /usr/share/applications/org.pantheon.files.desktop file, as changed the "Icon=system-file-manager" to point to the icon or picture location. "Icon=/location/to/picture/ico"

Comment: Man, the question is how to change the folders icons, not the icon of files app. Do you get it?